# Keep $location.search across different states in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So right now, I'm changing the url with:

```
$location.search(params);
```

But after I change the state (using ui-router), the url loses the parameters I set even though these states have no url defined. Is there something I can do to keep the url there across multiple states?

Answer (score 2):

In your app config section you can create a $urlRouterProvider.rule() to set the search params.

The rule is added at config, but it is run at runtime, so it can have a service injected that provide the search params.

```
$urlRouterProvider.rule(function($injector,  $location) {
    var yourParams = $injector.get('yourParams');
    $location.search(yourParams);
});
```